# GWT Query fails second time -only

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

HI,

I have a visualization function in GWT which calls for two instances of the same panels - two queries. Now, suppose one url is *A* and the other url is *B*. Here, I am facing an issue in that if *A* is called first, then both *A* and *B* works. If *B* is called first, then only *B* works, *A* - times out. If I call both times *A*, only the first time *A* works, second time it times out. If I call *B* twice, it works both times without a hitch.

Even though the error comes at timed out, it actually is not timing out - in FF status bar, it shows till - transferring data from *A*, and then it gets stuck. This doesnt even show up in the first time query.

The only difference between *A* and *B* is that *B* returns very fast, while *A* returns comparitively slow.

The sample code is given below:

```
public Panel(){
    Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          Query query = Query.create(dataUrl);
          query.setTimeout(60);
          query.send(new Callback() {
          public void onResponse(QueryResponse response) {
                  if (response.isError()){
                       Window.alert(response.getMessage());
                  }
              }
           }
      }
      VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE);
 }
```

What could be the reason for this? I cannot think of any reason why this should happen? Why is this happening only for *A* and not for *B*?

EDIT: More research.

The query which works all the time (i.e. *B* is the example URL given in GWT visualization site: see comment [1]). So, I tried in my app engine to reproduce it - the following way

```
    s = "google.visualization.Query.setResponse({version:'0.6',status:'ok',sig:'106459472',table:{cols:[{id:'A',label:'Source',type:'string',pattern:''},{id:'B',label:'Percent',type:'number',pattern:'#0.01%'}],rows:[{c:[{v:'Oil'},{v:0.37,f:'37.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Coal'},{v:0.25,f:'25.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Natural Gas'},{v:0.23,f:'23.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Nuclear'},{v:0.06,f:'6.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Biomass'},{v:0.04,f:'4.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Hydro'},{v:0.03,f:'3.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Solar Heat'},{v:0.005,f:'0.50%'}]},{c:[{v:'Wind'},{v:0.003,f:'0.30%'}]},{c:[{v:'Geothermal'},{v:0.002,f:'0.20%'}]},{c:[{v:'Biofuels'},{v:0.002,f:'0.20%'}]},{c:[{v:'Solar photovoltaic'},{v:4.0E-4,f:'0.04%'}]}]}});";
    response =  HttpResponse(s, content_type="text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    response['Expires'] = time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT', time.gmtime())
    return response
```

Where s is the data when we run the query for *B*. I tried to add Expires etc too, since that seems to be the only header which has the difference, but now, the query fails all the time.

For more info - I am now sending the difference between my server response vs the working server response. They seems to be pretty similar.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Wed, 16 Jun 2010 11:07:12 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Cache-Control: private, x-gzip-ok=""

google.visualization.Query.setResponse({version:'0.6',status:'ok',sig:'106459472',table:{cols:[{id:'A',label:'Source',type:'string',pattern:''},{id:'B',label:'Percent',type:'number',pattern:'#0.01%'}],rows:[{c:[{v:'Oil'},{v:0.37,f:'37.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Coal'},{v:0.25,f:'25.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Natural Gas'},{v:0.23,f:'23.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Nuclear'},{v:0.06,f:'6.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Biomass'},{v:0.04,f:'4.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Hydro'},{v:0.03,f:'3.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Solar Heat'},{v:0.005,f:'0.50%'}]},{c:[{v:'Wind'},{v:0.003,f:'0.30%'}]},{c:[{v:'Geothermal'},{v:0.002,f:'0.20%'}]},{c:[{v:'Biofuels'},{v:0.002,f:'0.20%'}]},{c:[{v:'Solar photovoltaic'},{v:4.0E-4,f:'0.04%'}]}]}});Connection closed by foreign host.


Mac$ telnet spreadsheets.google.com 80
Trying 209.85.231.100...
Connected to spreadsheets.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pWiorx-0l9mwIuwX5CbEALA&range=A1:B12&gid=0&headers=-1
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 16 Jun 2010 11:07:58 GMT
Expires: Wed, 16 Jun 2010 11:07:58 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE

google.visualization.Query.setResponse({version:'0.6',status:'ok',sig:'106459472',table:{cols:[{id:'A',label:'Source',type:'string',pattern:''},{id:'B',label:'Percent',type:'number',pattern:'#0.01%'}],rows:[{c:[{v:'Oil'},{v:0.37,f:'37.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Coal'},{v:0.25,f:'25.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Natural Gas'},{v:0.23,f:'23.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Nuclear'},{v:0.06,f:'6.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Biomass'},{v:0.04,f:'4.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Hydro'},{v:0.03,f:'3.00%'}]},{c:[{v:'Solar Heat'},{v:0.005,f:'0.50%'}]},{c:[{v:'Wind'},{v:0.003,f:'0.30%'}]},{c:[{v:'Geothermal'},{v:0.002,f:'0.20%'}]},{c:[{v:'Biofuels'},{v:0.002,f:'0.20%'}]},{c:[{v:'Solar photovoltaic'},{v:4.0E-4,f:'0.04%'}]}]}});Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Also, please note that App engine did not allow the Expires header to go through - can that be the reason? But if that is the reason, then it should not fail if *B* is sent first and then *A*.

Comment [1] : http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pWiorx-0l9mwIuwX5CbEALA&range=A1:B12&gid=0&headers=-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved. The reason for this error was that google QueryResponse function expects the response reqId to be incremented for each query in the same session - which I did not see documented anywhere. Once the reqId was incremented, it started working perfectly.